# Objective C: Query about releasing instance property

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I have a general query regarding memory management

```
//In .h file I defined a property
@interface AClass
{
    someClass *aProperty;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) someClass *aProperty;

end



//In .m file I synthesized the property and also initialized the property
@implementation AClass

-(void)aMethod
{
    self.aProperty = [[someClass alloc]init];
}
```

My question is

For 'aProperty', where do I do a 'release' to prevent a memory leak? I understand normally for instance properties (using dot notations), we do a release in the 'dealloc' and 'viewdidunload' methods. But for this instance, do I need to release aProperty again within the method 'aMethod'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You must release the instance in the **dealloc**
2. Your property initializations leaks the memory. You do alloc+init, retain inside the property, but don't release. Something like `self.property = [[[someClass alloc] init] autorelease]` is usually used.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `retain` in

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) someClass *aProperty;
```

any instance of `AClass` will automatically `retain` its property `aProperty`. Therefore you will need to call `[aProperty release]` in the `dealloc` method of `AClass`.

Every time you call `aMethod`, you are creating a new instance of `someClass` without release the previous instance. This will result in a huge leak. You can fix this in one of two ways. Either release the previous `aProperty` value or add in a call to `autorelease`.